# How to generate new line when to the page footer in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This image show write to the end

[image]

You can see i write code to the page footer, eclipse has no more line. I have to use enter to generate new line, I want know is there any way generate new line automate. or just set max line number to maximum, which I can never get to the end.
excuse my broken English...

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter is the way to generate the new lines automatically.
What is your problem with the enter key?

Comment: Yes, I know, press enter can generate new lines, but I'm lazy to press it. Is there someway to generate new line automatic just like excel have unlimited columns and row. Thanks a lot...